# Maven is not getting dependencies from Local Nexus repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies, nexus

I have installed Nexus locally. I have installed Maven Eclipse plugin (I did not download Maven, just it's Eclipse plugin). I have uploaded a sample JAR file using Nexus web page as 3rd part Artifact.
I have created a settings.xml [with these configuration](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20943003-Configure-Maven-to-Download-from-Nexus) in my .m2 folder.

I created a new Maven project in Eclipse and tried to use a class in the sample JAR file I uploaded. I disabled Workspace resolution on the project. I used Shift-Ctrl-O to import the dependencies automatically but it's not working. Is there any other step I need to take?

Comment: Well did you add the dependency to your POM?

Comment: I just found out about that. Now what if there are 100 jar files I want to add. Without Maven I just do 'Shift-Ctrl-O' and Eclipse does the rest. with maven I have to add each one to POM one by one?

Comment: You're wrong. Without Maven, you would have to download each dependency from _somewhere_ and add each one to the classpath manually (which is really _really_ horrible for lots of dependencies). With Maven, you add required depencies to the POM and it will download and add it to the classpath automatically.

Comment: But I have to "add required depencies to the POM" one by one, JAR by JAR?

Comment: Well at some point, if your project depends on 1000 libraries, you're going to have to tell Maven about it (would be exactly the same without it, as smart as the compiler is, it can't resolve your imports like that). If some of them are transitive dependencies, they will be included automatically however.

Comment: I thought Maven would read my code, identify classes that are missing dependencies, then go search repository and add decencies to POM Itself according to my code. Apparently its not that smart. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: No, Maven can't do that. Eclipse provides some facility to search your current m2 repository for missing imports but I'm not sure if it can be made automatic.

Comment: Last question since i'm new to this, what is the difference between Maven Eclipse plugin and the Maven zip file you download with /bin/ and all that.

Comment: Maven is an independant tool that helps manage projects. Eclipse is an IDE. Those 2 tools are uncorrelated. You could have a Maven project outside of Eclipse and compile on the command-line and everything would work. Now, as an IDE, it makes sense to use Eclipse to code Maven project so Eclipse has a plugin that interacts nicely with Maven: it is the M2Eclipse plugin.

Comment: so both do the same thing, but one is made for Eclipse and the other is just command based?

Comment: No, M2Eclipse plugin _uses_ a Maven installation to do its work and provides nice UI for Eclipse. By default, M2Eclipse plugin bundles a Maven installation of its own and uses that specific installation, but you can configure it to use a custom installation.

Comment: Is it good practice to update an artifact (JAR file) on nexus or its better to make new versions of it?

Comment: Never update an artifact in Nexus (except for SNAPSHOT's) and create a new version of it...